# Supernova remnant and ejecta "bullet"

Tags: supernova, x-ray, stellar-remnants, magnetar

I'm making an X-ray analysis of the source [SNR N49](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMC_N49). It has a magnetar inside of it that is emitting strongly in Soft ([0.2-1.2] keV), Medium ([1.2-2.5] keV), and Hard ([2.5-8.0] keV) bands.
I was seeing the following image: [image: Hard emission]

This is the Hard emission. You can see at the top of the remnant the magnetar contribution, but in the southwestern region there is a major contribution. In this paper [S.Park et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5056) they talk about this as an ejecta "bullet". What is this ejecta "bullet"?

Comment: I do not know why it deletes the firsts words of the questiion, this would say: I'm making an X-ray...

Comment: The paper you link states: "The highly overabundant Si and S firmly establish the identification of the bullet as metal-rich stellar fragment ejected from the deep interior of the progenitor star." That seems to make it pretty clear what it is. Maybe you can be more specific in your question.